# Fetching specific characeter from the string

Tags: c#

I want to know, how to fetch a specific character from a given string.

for Example, 
Consider the following strings

```
Value.1.name = S1
Value.2.name = S2
Value.3.name = S3
Value.4.name = S4
```

The code should return 1, 2,3,4 if the condition is S1,S2,S3 and S4 respectively. 
i.e it should only get the value between the two periods, Value.1.name should return 1.

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. `Value.1.name` is invalid varable name. Also it's unclear what `S1`,... are. Please reword your question and add more description and correct code.

Comment: What code, what condition? I'm afraid your question is pretty confusing to me at the moment. A [mcve] would really help - and ideally, as a console app, given that I don't see anything Winforms-specific here.

Comment: Give More information , what is mean of Value.1? read more about strings at http://www.dotnetperls.com/string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question is not clear. What i understood is you have to extract the number between dots if it matches number after 'S'.

Example: "Value.1.name = S1" is ok; "Value.1.name = S2" is not ok;

If that's the case here's a regex to get you started.

```
var input = "Value.1.name = S1";

var result = Regex.Matches( input, @"\.(\d)\..*S\1" );
foreach( var match in result.Cast<Match>() )
    Console.WriteLine( match.Groups[ 1 ].Value );
```